# Setting Input field to contain window.location.href

Tags: javascript, jquery, window.location

How do I get a input field to have the value of the current webpage URL using Javascript?

My proposed approach:

```
<script>
    var holder = window.location.href;
</script>

<input id="moo" value= holder>
```

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: @nicael- I clarified the question

Comment: But your code doesn't really appear to be relevant to the problem?..

Comment: None of this makes sense. Objective is not clear and doesn't seem to have any relation to the code shown. Please explain exactly what you want to accomplish and expected behaviors

Comment: A div has text or html not value

Comment: @charlietfl- You seem to know what my question is about. Thank you. Is their anyway to set the input field to have the value of the current page using the window.location.href method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set the value of a text input field to the location of the current page, first, we have to set up the HTML correctly:

```
<input type="text" id="moo">
```

With JavaScript, we can easily select this element with a call to `document.getElementById`, passing in the `id` of the text field as a parameter:

```
var input = document.getElementById("moo"); // "moo" is the 'id' of the text field
```

Now, we can assign the `value` of the text field to `location.href`:

```
input.value = location.href;
```

Now our input field will contain the location of the current webpage.

```js
var input = document.getElementById("moo"); // "moo" is the 'id' of the text field
input.value = location.href;
```

```html
<input type="text" id="moo">
```

Comment: Thank you! Great answer!

Answer (score -1):

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="url" placeholder="type the url to navigate to" />
<button id="search">
  search
</button>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    $("#search").click(function() {
    var url = $("#url").val();

    window.location.href = url;
  });
});
```